# Poscisionarse en columna y row especifico

Tags: c#, sql-server, windows-forms

Excelente día todos,

Tengo un listView el cual cargo con datos de un sp de Sql y ademas agrego al listView tres columnas vacías, esto para que mediante la interfaz gráfica el usuario pueda agregar valores a estos registros es decir en tiempo ejecución.

Este es el código de carga de datos del listView

```
private void getListView()
    {
        try
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Aprendizaje", cnx);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IdnomApp", cmbSelectApp.SelectedValue);
            da.Fill(dt);
            listaDatos.Clear();
            listaDatos.CheckBoxes = true;
            listaDatos.Columns.Add(dt.Columns[0].ToString(), 90);
            listaDatos.Columns.Add(dt.Columns[1].ToString(), 900);
            listaDatos.Columns.Add(dt.Columns[2].ToString(), 850);
            listaDatos.Columns.Add(dt.Columns[3].ToString(), 60);
            listaDatos.Columns.Add("Tecla", 60);
            listaDatos.Columns.Add("Evento", 60);
            listaDatos.Columns.Add("Coor", 60);

            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {
                string[] arr = new string[5];
                ListViewItem itm = new ListViewItem();

                for(int ncol = 0; ncol < 5; ncol++)
                {
                    arr[ncol] = row[ncol].ToString();
                    itm = new ListViewItem(arr);
                }
                listaDatos.Items.Add(itm);
            }
            cnx.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Ahora la pregunta es, en tiempo ejecución como me posiciono en la columna 5 row 1 para que el usuario comience a ingresar valores a estas columnas?
Los valores no son ingresados manualmente, para ello uso este método pero no me esta funcionando ya que ingresa los valores en la columna 1 ultima fila vacía:

```
private void CapturaEventos(string txt)
    {
         string[] lItems = txt.Split('-');
         listv= new ListViewItem(txt);

         listData.Items.Add("Tecla").SubItems.Add(lItems[0]);
         listData.Items.Add("Evento").SubItems.Add(lItems[1]);
         listData.Items.Add("Coor").SubItems.Add(lbl_Coor.Text.ToString());

    }

public void MouseMoved(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        lbl_Coor.Text = e.Location.X.ToString();


        if (e.Clicks > 0)
            CapturaEventos("Mouse - " + e.Button.ToString());
    }
```

Acá dejo una imagen como ejemplo, datos en color verde son Pre cargados desde Sql datos en color amarillo, es lo que el usuario debe capturar en tiempo ejecución.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La idea es indicarle al método Captura Eventos que comience a grabar los eventos desde la columna 5,1 6,1 y 7,1 siguiente linea 5,2,6,2 y 7,2 y así sucesivamente.

Les agradecería puedan ayudarme.

Erick

Answer (score 0):

Erick, es que estás "pisando" el valor de tu variable "itm" en cada iteración del for:

```
for(int ncol = 0; ncol < 5; ncol++)
{
    arr[ncol] = row[ncol].ToString();
    itm = new ListViewItem(arr);
}
listaDatos.Items.Add(itm);
```

Es decir, en la 1er iteración (ncol=0) asignas un valor a tu variable "itm". Luego en la 2da iteración (ncol=1) sobreescribes el valor de la misma variable, y así sucesivamente hasta terminar el ciclo.
Debes hacer lo siguiente:

```
for(int ncol = 0; ncol < 5; ncol++)
{
    arr[ncol] = row[ncol].ToString();
    listaDatos.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(arr));
}
```

¡Espero te ayude!

Comment: Creo lo del for no es el problema ya que con la carga de datos no tengo problemas.
El problema es posicionarme en la columna 5 row 1, en tiempo ejecución para que el método Captura Eventos comience a realizar su trabajo.
No se si mi explique?
@Matias Bello

Comment: Pero estás sobreescribiendo el valor de tu variable 5 veces (en realidad, 4, la primera es la asignación original). ¿Seguro ves correctamente los datos? Porque pareciera que sólo estás agregando 1 item con el valor de la última iteración de tu for.

Comment: Que tal, así es veo correctamente los datos, hice las correcciones que me comentas y lo que hizo es repetirme 5 veces los registros, es decir el IdCod se repite 5 veces en Sql y con la modificación del código me lo repitió 25 veces, 5 veces por registro.
@Matias Bello

Answer (score 0):

ahí entendí mejor..

En principio te recomiendo cambiar tu foreach, por este:

```
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
    {
        object valor = row[col];
        listaDatos.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(valor.ToString()));
    }
}
```

Es mas claro y más dinámico, así no tienes que preocuparte por cambiar el código si cambiar la cantidad de columnas.
Luego, aquí te dejo un método para establecer los valores de la fila que desees:

```
private void EstablecerValores(int nroFila, object[] valores)
{
    int itemsPorFila = 5;
    
    int posicion = itemsPorFila * nroFila;

    for(int i=0; i < valores.Length; i++)
    {
        listaDatos.Items[posicion + i] = new ListViewItem(valores[i].ToString());
    }
}
```

Al cual puedes llamar, por ejemplo, así:

```
EstablecerValores(5, new[] { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g" });
```

Lo que haces es pasar el número de fila a pisar los valores, y un array con los valores.